# How do I get socket.io to automatically compress my message?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` on my client and server.

As an example, I am sending a 5MB PDF from the server to the client:

```
const pdf = require('fs').readFileSync('5mb.pdf');

socket.compress(true).send(pdf);
```

However I am not sure if this is actually compressing...

I say this because I tried the same thing as above but with compression disabled and the **Length** for both shows up the same in Chrome's Dev Tools:

[image]

How do I verify if the compression is actually working? and how do I find out how effective the compression is?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off websocket secure if it's on.
Use wireshark to view the raw data.

I had the same question and couldn't find an answer.
Thus I did my analysis:

Chrome DevTools show that I send 3MB twice thus 6MB total.
In wireshark, I can see the beginning and end in raw text, but the middle is compressed looks like base64, Wireshark also only see around 1MB of data transferred total.

In Chrome DevTools, there is nothing I can see to inform me that it's compressed.

Answer (score -1):

PDF is already a compressed format. Therefore, most of the time, trying to compress one pdf file leads to nearly no changes.

You probably should do the same test with an ASCII file.